# Rules for multi-classing in D&D Next?

Tags: character-creation, dnd-next-playtest

I am participating in the D&D Encounters current season, which is being run with the recommended D&D Next ruleset. I am fond of the striker classes from 4e that combine martial with magic and divine aspects to improve or alter them – such as the avenger or hexblade warlock. Since the currently defined classes in Next are few and distinct. Presumably they are likely to remain that way for some time. I am interested in multi-classing a fighter with a cleric or wizard. I have looked through the playtest packet and do not see rules for multi-classing. I know that Encounters seasons are not long enough for a character to gain sufficiently high level to really take advantage of multi-classing but I am still curious and may use the concept of a fighter-cleric or fighter-wizard to inform my RP.

So what if any are the rules for multi-classing in D&D Next?

Comment: Out of date answers have been deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it no longer makes sense, with the multiclassing rules easily available.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WotC includes all (publicly available) rules in their playtest packets, so if it's not in the playtest packet then there are no rules for it at the moment.

As of Feb 28, 2013 no rules for multi-classing in DnD Next have been released.

---

**Update:** Here is a summary of the multiclassing rules in the players handbook.

Multiclassing is similar to 3<sup>rd</sup> edition in that each time you gain a level you choose what class to gain a level in. Unlike 3<sup>rd</sup> edition, classes now have ability score requirements to multi-class into them, either 13+ in one ability score or  two. You need the ability score of both your current class and your new one.

- You only gain 1st level hitpoints for your 1st class. Later classes always get the "after 1st level" HP, even if it's your 1st level in the class.
- Proficiency bonus is based on your total character level.
- Channel Divinity, Unarmored Defense, spells known and prepared, spell slots, pact magic & Extra Attack have special rules describing how they advance when you take levels in multiple classes that grant those features.
- Spells known are per-class, but spells per day are based on the sum of all your levels in bard/cleric/druid/sorcerer/wizard,  half your levels in paladin/ranger, and 1/3rd of your levels in Eldritch Knight/Arcane Trickster; that will probably give you spells of a higher level than you know. If it does, you can still cast spells in higher slots.
- Spellcasting & proficiency depend on the class the spell belongs to, but if it belongs to more than one of your classes you may choose which to use.
- Pact Magic. If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.
- When multiclassing into a new class you do not gain saving throw proficiencies.
- When multiclassing into a new class you get a limited number of proficiencies based on a table on page 164
- Hit dice are tracked per class.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly, there is no limit in the number of classes I can advance in, as long as the minimum ability requirements are met?

Answer (score 8):

Here I present the answer as of January, 2014:

Yes, the rules for multiclassing debuted in the playtest packet released at Sep. 19, 2013, which is the final playtest packet. In these rules, multiclassing requires you to have sufficient ability score for the class to dip in. (Specialties such as magic-user or mystical healer are cut off, by the way. You have to earn these abilities by obtaining a feat, which now requires you to sacrifice ability score increment of two points.)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to multiclass a fighter -cleric in DnD 5e, is to create a pure cleric and choose the war domain.

It really gives you everything you want mechanically. As a war cleric you gain access to heavy armor and martial weapons at level 1. You also gain bolts of inspiration which allow you to make an extra attack action a number of times equal to your wisdom modifier each day.  At level 2, you gain a +10 to your attack roll using channel divinity, and at level 6 you can give this +10 to another player.  At 8th level you gain 1d8 damage using spell slots on your attacks, and at level 14 this increases to 2d8 damage, then finally at level 17 you gain resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing non-magical damage. You also gain the spiritual weapon spell as a domain spell, which effectively gives another extra attack during battles in which you cast it. (Page 63 of the Players handbook)

However if you still want to multiclass, (to gain unique features from battlemaster, champions, or eldritch knights) you will need a 13+ in wisdom and a 13+ in strength or Dex before you are allowed to multi class.  Be aware that your spell slots will effectively be cut in half (or half + 1/3 if you mutliclass into eldritch knight). Your spell slots are determined by the new spell slot table on page 166 of the players handbook, with your effective casting level being your cleric level + 1/3 of your Eldritch knight level.

Also, your ability increases are based on class level not character level. Depending on how you multiclass, you also will still need the war domain to get access to all weapon and armor proficiencies.(heavy armor) which proficiencies you get depends on which class you pick first.

In general, when mutliclassing, your new class only gives a limited number of proficiencies from that class as outlined in the table on page 164 of the Players handbook.
The only proficiencies you gain when you multiclass into fighter is: Light armor, medium armor, shields, simple weapons, martial weapons.  (Page 164 of the Players Handbook)
The only proficiencies you gain when you multiclass into cleric is: Light armor, medium armor, shields. (Page 164 of the Players Handbook)

If you start as a cleric, you'll get prof bonus to wisdom & charisma saves, and access to light and medium armr, shields and simple weapons. (Page 45 of the Players Handbook)
If you start as a fighter, you'll get prof bonus to strength & constitution saves, and access to all armor, shields, simple weapons and martial weapons. (Page 45 of the Players Handbook)

When multiclassing you do not get the save proficiency from from the other class, and in the case of cleric and fighter you also don't gain any skills.  (Page 164 of the Players Handbook)

However as a war domain cleric you will get proficiencies to heavy armor and martial weapons. (Page 63 of the Players Handbook)

Comment: Ok, then I'll award the bounty on this answer. (In 19 hours once the timer is up.)